# upper case in name with accents

Tags: civimail, contacts, smarty

`{capture assign=last_name}{contact.last_name}{/capture}{$last_name|upper}`

I'm trying to render my contact name in uppercases with Smarty and include letters with accents.

At the bottom  of this page in the the Smarty doc: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.upper.tpl
It is advised to use `{$your_variable|@strtoupper}` but `{capture assign=last_name}{contact.last_name}{/capture}{$last_name|@strtoupper}` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want mb_strtoupper. Smarty's `|upper` just does strtoupper - you can see this if you look in packages/smarty/plugins/modifier.upper.php.

So one way is to hack modifier.upper.php and change it to use mb_strtoupper. You can also try using `{$last_name|@mb_strtoupper}` but it might give you a security error.

Comment: we did a PR for this modification in code in `packages/smarty/plugins/modifier.upper.php`

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/325 but for a better fix I would now suggest proposing something for civi core like [mb_truncate](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/b6601e07a902dcffcb9c46e113c52d7020aa8066/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/modifier.mb_truncate.php).

Comment: See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20892